# Modify a JSON using Jolt Transform

Tags: json, jolt

I have an array of JSONs as listed below:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 3
  }
]
```

The following are the objectives:

(1) Modify the list above into:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
  "idList": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
}
```

(2) Calculate the Minimum and Maximum of "idList" to finally obtain:

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3
    }
  ],
    "minID": 1,
    "maxID": 3,
}
```

I think (2) is straightforward after getting (1), as I can simply use:

```
min(@(1,idList))
```

I have a problem in converting the original input into (1), here's my attempt:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "data"
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": { "*": { "id": "idList" } }
    }
  }
]
```

which yields:

```
{
  "idList" : [ 1, 2, 5 ]
}
```

Can anyone help on this?
Also, am a newbie to this Jolt Transform technique, can anyone suggest a good source for mastering this ? (like a book)

Comment: There are some good sources and links : [1-Jolt Playground](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/) , [2-Releases](https://github.com/bazaarvoice/jolt/releases), [3-A Good Blog](https://erbalvindersingh.medium.com/applying-jolttransform-on-json-object-array-and-fetching-specific-fields-48946870b4fc), [4-Another Good Blog](https://intercom.help/godigibee/en/articles/3159219-transformer-operations-overview), [5-A Tutorial](https://cool-cheng.blogspot.com/2019/12/json-jolt-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consecutively use a **shift**, and **modify** transformation specs such as

```json
[
  {
    // for the first objective
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "data",
        "*": "idList"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    // for the second one
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "minID": "=min(@(1,idList))",
      "maxID": "=max(@(1,idList))"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is

[image]